# How do we include Android.bp in vendor/manufacturer/device

Tags: android, android-soong

I have created Android.bp in vendor/manufacturer/device/module/Android.bp

> Android.bp

```
prebuilt_etc {
    name: "foo",
    src: "bar",
    vendor: true,
}
```

when I run mka foo ninja doesnt see the module but soong can find errors in the Android.bp when its first scanning through directories